# Is it possible to search within a MySQL JSON array in a case insensitive manner?

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-5.7

e.g. with the table:

```sql
create table test (id int primary key, tags json);
insert into test (id, tags) values (1, '["Lorem ipsum", "dolor", "sit"]'), (2, '["foo", "bar"]');
```

This will match:

```sql
select id from test where json_search(tags, 'one', 'Lorem%') is not null
```

But this will not:

```sql
select id from test where json_search(tags, 'one', 'lorem%') is not null
```

Ideally I'd like to be able match both cases.

Running on 5.7.16 Percona XtraDB Cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other case, when You can not change data and must have proper result:

```
select 
    id 
from test 
where json_search(UPPER(tags), 'one', UPPER('lorem%')) is not null
```

will be slower of course, so need test on real data-size

Comment: I didn't realise that UPPER() would work on json types - that'll certainly do for my purposes, I'll only need to scan a handful of rows like this at any time.

Comment: @a_vlad Use `lower()` instead of `upper()`, as JSON `null`, `true` and `false` must be lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is related to the Search value not being a _ci charset.
Json_search() allows case insensitive searches as long as your collation of datatable is _ci and you search parameter is _ci as well.

To solve this in a stored procedure using prepared statement i had to do the following

```
SET @theQuery = "select *
from `theTable`
where
 json_search( 
  `theTable`.`myJsonColumn`, 
  'all', 
  CONVERT( ? USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, 
  NULL, 
  '$.KeyName' 
) IS NOT NULL";

prepare stmt from @theQuery;
execute stmt using @searchValue;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

See explaination from documentation on json_Search if you need to learn more about the parameters in json_search.

Note that the ? inside the Select-Query is the inparameter from prepared statement using @searchValue param.

[Mysql doc - json_search()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)

[Mysql doc - Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

This is more efficient than doing a lower() or upper() conversion and as i noticed, you cant specify a key to search against if you do use lower() or upper().

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the collation that is used by the table or the field. If it is case sensitive, then "L" would not match "l". 
In order to know the collation, run this please:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE test`

Collation names that are case insensitive end with "_ci". [Click here for more info about Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-names.html).

Comment: Sorry Jehad I should have mentioned that upfront - this is with utf8_general_ci.  The json searches seem to be case sensitive even with a _ci collation.